# IRM in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, irm

How to configure Information Rights Management (IRM) in SharePoint Foundation?

I tried to Enable in Central Adminstration - > System Settings - > IRM.

But i am getting this warning message.

The required Windows Rights Management client is present but could not be configured properly. IRM will not work until the WRM client is configured properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add few permission roles, follow steps below,

> The steps for configuring SharePoint Server role permissions are as
> follows:
>
> On the RMS server, navigate to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot_wmcs\Certification.
>
> Right-click the ServerCertification.asmx file and choose Properties,
> and then click the Security tab.
>
> Click Edit and then Add. Click Object
> Types, select Computers, and then click OK.
>
> Enter the name of all
> SharePoint web roles servers into the box and then click OK.
>
> Click
> Add. Technorati Tags: AD RMS,Information Rights Management,SharePoint
> 2010 Select Object Types of Groups, and then click OK.
>
> Type
> RMSServer\AD RMS Service Group (where RMSServer is the name of your
> RMSServer), and then click OK. Review the security settings, which
> should be similar to what is shown in Figure 5.
>
> Figure 1. Modifying the security on the ServerCertification.asmx file
> on the RMS server.
>
> Click OK to close the security dialog box.

[image]

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richin/archive/2012/02/05/ad-rms-configuration-error-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

If that doesn't solve your solution then,

> To use IRM in Office SharePoint Server 2007, you must install the
> Microsoft Windows Rights Management Services Client, version 1, on
> every front-end Web server in your server farm.   In addition,
> Microsoft Windows Rights Management Services (RMS) for Windows Server
> 2003, service pack 1.0 or later, must be available on your network.
> To install the Windows Rights Management Services Client, and for
> additional information about Microsoft Windows Rights Management
> Services, visit the Windows Rights Management Services Technology
> Center (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=73121).   For a
> description of the steps needed to configure Microsoft Windows Rights
> Management Services to allow Office SharePoint Server 2007 to create
> rights-managed content, see Deployment for Office SharePoint Server
> 2007.   For more information, please refer to: Plan Information Rights Management (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261728.aspx)

[For more information](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/cc87da79-e66b-4415-bdc3-541431bc22f4)